# URL Redirect with BlogEngine

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, blogengine.net

I am in the process of moving Blog from dasBlog to BlogEngine.  In dasBlog, my URLs looks like this.

> http://pfsolutions-mi.com/blog/2008/03/08/Beyond-Compare.aspx

Whereas in BlogEngine, my URLs looks like this.

> http://pfsolutions-mi.com/blog/post/2008/03/08/Beyond-Compare.aspx

The only difference between the two URLs is the "post" sub-folder in BlogEngine.

Since I'm currently using IIS URL Rewrite to remove WWW from the URL, I figured the easiest solution would be to create another rule to handle adding the sub-folder.  I tried something like this.

> rule name="Blog Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"
>
> match url="^blog/([_0-9]+)/([_0-9]+)/([_0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+).([_0-9a-z-]+)$"
>
> action type="Redirect" url="blog/post/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:4}.{R:5}" redirectType="Temporary"

However, when I enter an old dasBlog URL it does not get redirected to the new location.  Instead I get the generic BlogEngine 404 Error page.

Note: I plan to change the redirectType to Permanent once I know everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your matching regex look more like this?

```
match url="^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)\.([a-z]+)$"
```

There are no underlines in date numbers anyway and your `[_0-9a-z-]+` doesn't include uppercase letters like in "Beyond-Compare".

So here we should have: url="^blog/digits/digits/digits/any-word-characters.lowercase-letters$"

We could also specify more with:

```
match url="^blog/([0-9]{2,4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([\w-]+)\.([a-z]{3,4})$"
```

Based on the assumption that you always have:

1. Year as "08" or "2008"
2. Month and day as "01" or "11"
3. File endings with 3 or 4 lowercase letters (htm, html, php, asp, aspx, etc.)

EDIT: I think "\w+" does not include hyphen, so you must turn this into "[\w-]+"

Comment: Sorry, but that did not fix the problem.  I'm doubting that it is a "match url" issue because both (yours and mine) regular expressions passed the matching expression test in the IIS Manager URL Rewrite utility.

Comment: Maybe we should just test that with a most simple regex (like "^blog/.*$"), if it is assuredly not the problem we can search for other causes, but in most cases rewritten 404s are caused by wrong regex.